# Let's win at Python Lucky Number

Tags: python, python-3.x

The previous day, I helped someone build a really simple console "Lucky Number" game. It's really simple, the user has to choose a number, the program will also choose one, and if there's a match between the two, the user wins.

To made the game a bit more visual, the numbers are initially blue and displayed in a nice way.

I'm looking for the following things in a review, but any advice is welcome:

- is the code structured ok?
- did I use the correct data structures along the program? (e.g.: is it okay for `Colors` to be an `Enum`, should `numbers` be a `number`: `color` map and so on)
- are type annotations used correctly?
- are the function / variable names suggestive enough?
- is there anything in terms of performance that can be improved?

Here's the code:

```
import random
import sys
import time

from enum import Enum
from typing import Dict


LINE_WIDTH = 5
EXTRA_PADDING = 6

# seconds to wait until the next number
# is picked up
SECONDS_TO_WAIT = 5

MIN_NUMBER = 1
MAX_NUMBER = 30


class Colors(Enum):
   red = '\033[91m'
   green = '\033[92m'
   blue = '\033[94m'
   end = '\033[0m'


def assign_color_to_number(number: int, default_color: str) -> str:
   """
   Show ANSI colors in terminal for nicer UX.

   Arguments:
       number (int): A number between `MIN_NUMBER` and `MAX_NUMBER`
       default_color (str): The color of a number

   Returns:
       str: Each number with it's own color
   """

   for color in Colors:
       if color.name == default_color:
           return f'{color.value}{number}{Colors.end.value}'
   else:
       return f'{number}'


def print_table(numbers_color_map: Dict[int, str]) -> None:
   """
   Print a nice table with colorful numbers wrapped after
   `LINE_WIDTH` numbers.

   Arguments:
       numbers_color_map (dict): A map between numbers and their color.
   """

   print('\n')

   padding = max([int(len(color.name)) for color in Colors]) + len(str(MAX_NUMBER)) + EXTRA_PADDING

   for number, default_color in numbers_color_map.items():
       colored_number = assign_color_to_number(number, default_color).ljust(padding)
       print(colored_number, end=' ') if number % LINE_WIDTH != 0 else print(colored_number)

   print('\n')


def countdown(seconds: int) -> None:
   """
   Let user know how much until the next game.

   Arguments:
       seconds (int): How many seconds until next game.
   """

   for second in range(seconds, -1, -1):
       sys.stdout.write(f"\r{second} seconds remaining until next "
                        f"number will be picked.")
       time.sleep(1)
       sys.stdout.flush()

   print('\n')


def get_user_number() -> int:
   """
   Sanitize user's input.

   Returns:
       int: User's chosen number.
   """

   while True:
       try:
           value = int(input(f'Please chose a number between '
                             f'{MIN_NUMBER} and {MAX_NUMBER}: '))

           if MAX_NUMBER < value < MIN_NUMBER:
               print(f"Please insert a number between {MIN_NUMBER} and "
                     f"{MAX_NUMBER}!\n")
               continue

           return value
       except ValueError:
           print(f"Please insert a number between {MIN_NUMBER} and "
                 f"{MAX_NUMBER}!\n")
           continue


def play():
   numbers_color_map = {
       number: 'blue' for number in range(MIN_NUMBER, MAX_NUMBER + 1)
   }

   print_table(numbers_color_map)

   user_number = get_user_number()
   print(f"You chose {user_number}. GOOD LUCK!\n\n")

   countdown(SECONDS_TO_WAIT)

   random_number = random.randint(MIN_NUMBER, MAX_NUMBER)

   if user_number != random_number:
       numbers_color_map.update({
           random_number: 'green',
           user_number: 'red'
       })
       print_table(numbers_color_map)

       print(f'    Your number: {user_number}\n'
             f'Computer number: {random_number}\n\n'
             f'You did not win. GOOD LUCK NEXT TIME!')
   else:
       print('You guessed it! Congrats! Please fill in the information '
             'below in order to receive your prize.\n\n')

   # reset our numbers to their initial color
   numbers_color_map.update({
       random_number: 'blue',
       user_number: 'blue'
   })


def main():

   while True:
       os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

       print('\nWELCOME TO THE LUCKY NUMBER!')

       play()

       answer = input('\nPlay again? [Y]es/[N]o: ')
       if answer.lower() == 'n':
           break

   print('\nTHANKS FOR PLAYING!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

You can either c/p the code and run it locally or [play it here](https://repl.it/@alexu/LotteryGameRST-1#main.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I really enjoyed reviewing this code, it is very readable and understandable. The code looks nice. I would just highlight few things that might be improve

### Reduce the use of Globals

You want to always reduce your use of global variables. In your program, you have a lot of global variables, you can eliminate all of them by encapsulating them in a `datatclass`. I would not expect `MIN_NUMBER` and `MAX_NUMBER` to be constant as they might change.

Here I created a data class named `LuckyGameConfig` and hide some configuration data in it

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass 
class LuckyGameConfig:
    """Lucky number guessing game configurations""" 

    line_width: int = 5
    padding: int = 6
    seconds_to_wait: int = 5
    min_number: int = 1
    max_number: int = 30
```

This looks better now, we know where to look when we need to modify how we want our game to look.

### Prefer `colorama` Module to ANSI Color

I see you created a nice `Enum` class to hold your colors, `colorama` module shines here, it makes what you are doing really easy.

```
from colorama import init, Fore
```

We can simply create a green color

```
green_color = Fore.GREEN
Fore.RESET # reset our color
```

The module also have styles like `BOLD`, `ITALIC`, you might want to check the module out.

### Reduce `print_table` Complexity

A lot of stuff are going on in `print_table`. The name is also misleading, what table are we printing here. It would not take much to get confused on what is really going on in the function.

Why smashed this into one line?

```
 print(colored_number, end=' ') if number % LINE_WIDTH != 0 else print(colored_number)
```

This looks smart but confuses the reader, he/she would need to pause a little to understand this piece of code.

This following can also be improved.

```
padding = max([int(len(color.name)) for color in Colors]) + len(str(MAX_NUMBER)) + EXTRA_PADDING
```

Let's call our function `display_numbers`

```
def display_numbers(numbers: dict) -> None:
    """Display a nice table with colorful numbers wrapped.

    Arguments:
        numbers (dict): A dict of numbers that maps to its color
    """
    for number, color in numbers.items():
        if number % LuckyGameConfig.line_width != 0:
            format = f'{number:<{LuckyGameConfig.padding}}'
            print(color, format, end=' ')
        else:
            print(color, number)
    print(Fore.RESET)
```

This looks more readable.

### Fix the Bug

The little bug in your program. Choosing a number greater than `MAX_NUMBER` or less than `MIN_NUMBER` seems to work. On inspecting the code, I found that you wrote this test

```
 if MAX_NUMBER < value < MIN_NUMBER:
```

Let's see a simple example, say the user chooses 90, the condition evaluates to `30 < 90 < 1` which is `False`, the condition statement never evaluates and the error passes silently and `value` is initialized.

The bug can be fixed like this

```
if value < MIN_NUMBER or value > MAX_NUMBER:
```

The full code becomes

```
"""A random lucky number game"""

import sys
import time
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
from colorama import init, Fore 
from random import randint
from typing import Dict 


@dataclass 
class LuckyGameConfig:
    """Lucky number guessing game configurations""" 

    line_width: int = 5
    padding: int = 6
    seconds_to_wait: int = 5
    min_number: int = 1
    max_number: int = 30 


def display_numbers(numbers: dict) -> None:
    """Display a nice table with colorful numbers wrapped.

    Arguments:
        numbers (dict): A dict of numbers that maps to its color
    """
    for number, color in numbers.items():
        if number % LuckyGameConfig.line_width != 0:
            format = f'{number:<{LuckyGameConfig.padding}}'
            print(color, format, end=' ')
        else:
            print(color, number)
    print(Fore.RESET)

def get_user_number() -> int:
   """
   Sanitize user's input.

   Returns:
       int: User's chosen number.
   """

   while True:
       try:
           value = int(input(f'Please chose a number between '
                             f'{LuckyGameConfig.min_number} and {LuckyGameConfig.max_number}: '))

           if value < LuckyGameConfig.min_number or value > LuckyGameConfig.max_number:
               print(f"Please insert a number between {LuckyGameConfig.min_number} and "
                     f"{LuckyGameConfig.max_number}!\n")
               continue

           return value
       except ValueError:
           print(f"Please insert integer values!\n")
           continue

def countdown(seconds: int) -> None:
   """
   Let user know how much until the next game.

   Arguments:
       seconds (int): How many seconds until next game.
   """

   for second in range(seconds, -1, -1):
       sys.stdout.write(f"\r{second} seconds remaining until next "
                        f"number will be picked.")
       time.sleep(1)
       sys.stdout.flush()

   print('\n')

def play():
    """Play a lucky number guessing game""" 

    init() # initialize colorama to get our basic colors
    numbers = {number: Fore.BLUE for number in range(LuckyGameConfig.min_number, LuckyGameConfig.max_number + 1)}
    display_numbers(numbers)
    user_number = get_user_number()
    print(f"You chose {user_number}. GOOD LUCK!\n\n")

    countdown(LuckyGameConfig.seconds_to_wait)
    random_number = randint(LuckyGameConfig.min_number, LuckyGameConfig.max_number)

    if user_number != random_number:
        numbers.update({
            random_number: Fore.GREEN,
            user_number: Fore.RED
        })
        display_numbers(numbers)

        print(f'    Your number: {user_number}\n'
                f'Computer number: {random_number}\n\n'
                f'You did not win. GOOD LUCK NEXT TIME!')
    else:
        print('You guessed it! Congrats! Please fill in the information '
                'below in order to receive your prize.\n\n')

    # we do not need to reset the colors, the while loop in main does the job

def main():

    while True:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print('\nWELCOME TO THE LUCKY NUMBER!')
        play()
        answer = input('\nPlay again? [Y]es/[N]o: ')
        if answer.lower() == 'n':
           break

        print('\nTHANKS FOR PLAYING!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Nice review. Regarding **Fix the Bug** I find `if not MIN_NUMBER <= value <= MAX_NUMBER:` nice to read.

Answer (score 2):

Nice implementation, the code is well structured and easy to understand. My suggestions:

- **Printing the table**: there are two variables to configure how to display the numbers:

  ```
  LINE_WIDTH = 5
  EXTRA_PADDING = 6
  ```

  `LINE_WIDTH` seems to be how many numbers can be displayed for each line, so a better name could be `NUMBERS_PER_LINE`. The variable `EXTRA_PADDING` is ok but I would document it in the `print_table` function.
- **Bug**: this condition doesn't catch the wrong input:

  ```py
  if MAX_NUMBER < value < MIN_NUMBER:
      print(f"Please insert a number between {MIN_NUMBER} and {MAX_NUMBER}!\n")
  ```

  Assuming that `MIN_NUMBER` and `MAX_NUMBER` are valid options, you can change it to:

  ```
  if value < MIN_NUMBER or value > MAX_NUMBER:
      print(f"Please insert a number between {MIN_NUMBER} and {MAX_NUMBER}!\n")
  ```
- **Colors**:

  ```
  class Colors(Enum):
  red = '\033[91m'
  green = '\033[92m'
  blue = '\033[94m'
  end = '\033[0m'
  ```

  The color `end` is a bit confusing for an enum called `Colors`. Consider `ANSIColorCode` as a name, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).
- **Design**: the logic to display the numbers is interesting but not very easy to reuse. Suppose I want to reuse it, I need to copy the functions `assign_color_to_number`, `print_table`, `Colors`, and the two constants to configure how to display the numbers. Plus understanding how to create and use the map `numbers_color_map`. Consider creating a class for it, like `TablePrinter` or `RangePrinter`, to make it easier to reuse and test. For example:

  ```
  class RangePrinter:
    NUMBERS_PER_LINE = 5
    EXTRA_PADDING = 6

    def __init__(self, start, end, default_color='blue'):
        # Initialize the map setting all numbers to default_color
    def print(self):
        # Print numbers to console
    def set_number_to_color(self, number, color):
        # Set color for a single number
    def set_all_numbers_to_color(self, color):
        # Set color for all numbers
  ```